# flash videos are missing from PDF after compression with ghostscript

Tags: linux, pdf, ghostscript

I am trying to compress some PDF documents using ghost-script, the documents i am trying to compress contain flash video embedded in the documents, i am converting using the following command:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

When opening the resulted document i cannot start the flash video. simply it's not in the resulted file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the 'Overview' in VectorDevices.htm ? (you will need the latest version of Ghostscript, or you can view it online from ghostscript.com)

So, you are not 'compressing' the PDF, you are creating a brand new PDF, the aim of which is that the visual appearance should be the same.

Now, the Ghostscript PDF interpreter does not support flash videos (or indeed any other video), because there's nothing sensible you can do with a video on paper. The result of this is that it does not preserve the data stream. Since it doesn't do so the pdfwrite device clearly can't embed it in the output PDF file.

Comment: Thanks for the description, that makes sense.